# Simple php image rotation wont save the new rotation

Tags: php, gd

I see a ton of topics asking about this here, but all of them are people who cannot get their image to rotate at all.  I can get the rotate to work, my problem is that it won't save the new image rotation.

I used this code

```
    if ( $_GET['rotate'] == 1 )
    {
        
        $filename = '/path/to/image/test.jpg';
        $degrees = 180;
    

        // Content type
        header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

        // Load
        $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

        // Rotate
        $rotate = imagerotate($source, $degrees, 0);

        // Output
        imagejpeg($rotate);

        // Free the memory
        imagedestroy($source);
        imagedestroy($rotate);
        
        exit();
    }
```

It works great.  When I click on the link the image rotates 180 degrees.  However it doesn't save the image like that. When I go back and refresh the page the image is at its original angle. I actually tried a lot of things before posting here but I am sorry I lost the changes I made. I did try to use:

rename($rotate,$filename);

to see if that would work but it doesn't.  Is there additional code added to save the image?  I would like the image file name to remain the same if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are just rotating the image in memory when accessing the php file with ?rotate=1 and sending that rotated image to the browser, instead of saving it to disk. It looks like you are missing `imagejpeg($rotate, $filename);`. This will update the image on disk.

Sidenote: Keep in mind it is a good idea to keep the original of your image instead of overwriting it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I replaced imagejpeg($rotate); with imagejpeg($rotate, $filename); and it just resulted in a blank white page.  The error log did have a message about failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in (path).  I googled that error and people say you have to use the path and I am using a path and not urls

Comment: Yes, but now the image on disk will have been rotated :) If you want to send the rotated image to the browser as well as save it on disk you need `imagejpeg($rotate, $filename); imagejpeg($rotate);`

Comment: Sorry still not working :(  When I say its a just a blank white page I meant that it doesn't rotate it either when I look at the image again.

Comment: What does the `imagejpeg($rotate, $filename)` return? If it returns false, are you sure the php process can write to the path in $filename?

Comment: Yes I know the path is writable since another script is what moved that image file to that directory.  I use FTP to upload a lot of images of receipts to one directory, then I review them on another webpage, then post/rename the files into the final directory where this file I am trying to rotate is located.  Now I would like to rotate some of the images and when I click on the rotate link it rotates, but it doesn't save it like that.  Maybe I should try chmod 777 before this command and chmod the file back to 644?

Comment: Does the `imagejpeg` call return true or false?

Comment: Sorry I am not really sure what you mean since I am not a programmer.  Just a guy who works on my own website to use features without having to use a laggy app filled with ads and gets updated with slower features or changes the entire layout.  I like having my own site to use tools that never change around

Comment: I'm afraid I can't really help you if you are not able to follow my questions/instructions. I do understand your desire though, and I wish you the best of luck!

Comment: I wish to do everything you say.  When you say does it return true or false, I am not seeing any message.  It just rotates the image and when I look at the image after refreshing it is back to where it was.

Comment: I think I figured it out.  I cannot overwrite the same file, but I can rotate a new file.  I will add a new code to unlink the original file and rename the new one to take its place as a rotation